# What is the procedure for users who just copy answers?

Tags: discussion

Consider Ooh Yaa https://stackoverflow.com/users/2310444/ooh-yaa

The first two answers from this user are blatant copies of correct answers.

- [disable past dates on datepicker "without using JQuery UI"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15802572/disable-past-dates-on-datepicker-without-using-jquery-ui/16164621#16164621)
- [Calculating geometric mean of a long list of random doubles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16164373/calculating-geometric-mean-of-a-long-list-of-random-doubles/16164689#16164689)

They had one upvote each (I've since downvoted both). Perhaps the start of some unethical play?

What can be done?

Comment: Just flag for moderator attention. Use the "other" option and explain the situation.

Comment: They did at least go through the bother of fixing the formatting error in the first copied answer, and made the second copied answer more readable. ;)

Comment: Two Votes on his answer, and he started voting, see his votes, 9 Question & 15 Answers

Comment: @Bart That slipped my mind. I've now flagged.

Comment: @Lucifer I don't understand what you mean? Could you explain?

Comment: @KevinBrydon That's the best option next time. There is no need to drag individual cases out in public. (With all the flags, downvotes and other consequences that might have). Just flag for moderator attention and let them deal with it.

Comment: @KevinBrydon Lucifer means, the probable only reason they posted copied answers was to get two quick upvotes and enough rep to serial-upvote another person's questions and answers.

Comment: Arrr...I slipped (kind of), this might be better suited: [What to do about Copy Cat answers?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93755/what-to-do-about-copy-cat-answers)

Comment: @J.Steen Thanks. I understand now! Is there procedure in place to detect these users? It's slightly annoying.

Comment: @KevinBrydon If they do proceed to serially upvote other users, they will most likely be found out, yes.

Comment: @KevinBrydon, That means it is sock-puppet ID, for upvoting posts.

Comment: @Bart I didn't want to single out a particular user but I've seen this a few times and thought I'd use this as an example.

Comment: I am on my phone, so I don't have access to all the tools, but that nickname and behavior set off bells! If they still exist when I get to a computer... bwahahaha!!

Comment: UNLEASH THE BARBER!!!

Comment: @Bart I am seriously concerned; I enjoy this stuff *way* more than I should!

Comment: @AndrewBarber as an evil overlord should. Nothing to be concerned about.