# what should we do when a user copy answer and did not mention original?

Tags: discussion, answers, attribution, plagiarism

I know something like this has asked before [What to do about Copy Cat answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93755/what-to-do-about-copy-cat-answers) But my question is slightly different.

What should we do when some user just copied the content from another answer from `SO` or from other web resources, and they never mention it?

After leaving some comment on the post they mention but again they forget to mention the original post while answering a question. What should we do in that cases?

Comment: Depends. In the worst case, you flag and wait for it to burn. Do you have an example?

Comment: yes http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21167077/android-split-function-alternative/21167239#comment32144238_21167239 this one and the user always doing this. Some other user has posted to include original attribute. But again he misses it.

Comment: Oh. That's blatant plagiarism. Flag and burn.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Good catch. And as always with plagiarizers, it's not the only copy & pasted answer.

If you feel like doing the work, you can go through the guy's profile and Google-test all his answers for plagiarism. Then flag each occurrence where you find plagiarism for moderator attention, and write "plagiarism: " and then the original URL.

Do this for each item separately, as moderators can't be expected to dig for more.

You can also add the same message as a comment, and/or nicely educate the author, but you don't have to.

**Edit**: OK, this guy is really sneaky. Mods, please stop him.

- [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21155030/pas-value-through-intent-or-static-variable/21155090#21155090) reworded plagiarism of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9547058/should-i-pass-info-using-intent-or-use-a-static-variables)
- [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21130141/187606) plagiarism of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10618918/187606) (seriously?)#
- [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21129562/187606) plagiarism of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16684203/187606)

... and plenty more, pretty much every one of his contributions.

Comment: I have just seen one example right now ;-) you know what i am talking about

Comment: Yeah, and he knows exactly what he's doing.

Comment: another one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21158932/why-it-is-discouraged-to-use-autorequery-in-cursoradapter/21159060#21159060

Comment: His [**very first**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19385318) answer is copy pasta :/ (edit: it just vanished, now 10k only)

Comment: @brasofilo yeah, 95% of his stuff is. I've gone through pages 1-3 (ordered by votes), calling it a day now, if anybody else wants to go on there's plenty :)

Comment: While Googling the other guy's stuff, I also came across this user: http://stackoverflow.com/users/1265724/ram-kiran who needs a close look

Comment: @brasofilo i think his answer is removed from there..

Comment: @user moderators will delete answers they confirm as plagiarism.

Comment: @Pëkka, I think this comment is for you - it seems you're now known as Plagiarism http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21155030/pas-value-through-intent-or-static-variable/21155090#comment32146146_21155090

Comment: @Plagiarism, plz stap!

Comment: @PeterJ that's actually a catchy name!

Comment: @ALienArrays yeah. A mod has since nuked the questions I'd already flagged but I'll wait with the rest. He's suspended for plagiarism though, can he edit stuff in the meanwhile?

Answer (score 5):

Flag it for moderator attention, and explain the problem using a custom flag.

In some cases, the moderators may already know about the problem.  The SE software detects copy/paste posts, and raises an automatic moderator flag when it happens.  But cast the flag anyway. It provides confirmation to the moderator that it is actually a problem.

Copying from other sites is a bit trickier.  In some cases, [Fair Use](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fair_use) applies.  But if it's clearly a case of blatant plagiarism, say so in the flag.  Don't raise copyright issues in a moderator flag; mods are not empowered to do anything about copyright claims.

Comment: Copying is fine at some extent but shouldn't we mention the original post.

Comment: Generally, yes.

Comment: you can see what i mean in 1 hour so many flagged answer. and all are plagiarism

Comment: @Alien: I just love it when people come up with new straw men to chew on.

Comment: @AlienArrays - There's a very large difference between reusing or building upon code and copying word-for-word sentences and paragraphs from other sources. The system doesn't automatically flag any of this, and we can distinguish between degrees of copying.