# You answer my question, I answer yours

Tags: support, stack-overflow, sock-puppets

Recently while visiting a question, I saw two users on Stack Overflow and found uncanny activity. So I visited their profile and saw that these users might be committing vote fraud.  One user is asking and accepting questions from a specific user and vice versa.

Now there is no rule against one user frequently answering another user's question, but if this happens quite frequently then I guess something might be going on.

I believe they are sock-puppets. What can I do in such a situation?

Comment: If that's the case, he'll be caught soon, don't worry.

Comment: don't worry except maybe you should worry, for every fake question opened there are people who will work not only to attempt the unobtainable, but will also accomplish nothing to help noone except maybe some other user who happen to have a similar question

Comment: They could just be friends… (not to imply that that activity is normal or acceptable)

Comment: They could be friend, but copying other users answer and paste it as his answer ( later on accepting such answer ) is purly not acceptable.

Comment: If some one just copy the answer and not mentioning the real attribute. This is just plagiarism. You can flag these post. See this one http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/217304/what-should-we-do-when-a-user-copy-answer-and-did-not-mention-original

Comment: How can we stop this kind of situation? I mean, if someone just call their friends to do some favors for them, how can we stop them?

Comment: @AveMaleficum we can only flag or report on meta. Moderator can stop them, if it is voting irregularities case.

Comment: @AveMaleficum - The only option is "flag". In such cases just flag one of their posts and explain the situation there. If a moderator find any evidence, it will suspend them for X days (it's up to the situation).

Comment: Just flag the situation. Use the "other" option and clearly explain what you're seeing. There is generally no need to bring such specific cases up on Meta.